# How tell angular cli not change url in css files?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I am using angular 7 in my project have images in folder `src/assets/image/logo.png`. The image I use in style.scss:

```
.logo {
baground-image: url('./src/assets/image/logo.png');
}
```

After building my project the image move to the root folder `/logo.png`.

How tell angular cli not change url in css files?
Help me, please.

Comment: How to configure angular (CLI) keep `url('./src/assets/image/logo.png')` after build project  in style.scss?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
.logo {
   baground-image: url('assets/image/logo.png');
}
```

and verify that 'assets' is configured in angular-cli.json

```
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
...
```